# CSS scroll problems

Tags: html, css, scroll

I used `overflow-y:auto;` to create a scroll inside a box with text.

For some reason when I use it, it jumps back up!

Do you know what's the problem is?
(If it helps, the box is opened when mouse hovering a picture, but no problem here I think)

Comment: Please provide relevant code and, if possible, a [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: perhaps post a little more information, like example of code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: You have some sort of funky Javascript going on with it. It doesn't allow you to highlight text, or anything. Your Javascript is what is messing it up. Do you have a `mouseover` or `hover` event set? You can't even scroll it manually.

Comment: onmouseover! yeah, really awkward. I'll try to disable the js files

Comment: @Kacey any suggestion? I'm really blank here... How could I use google Chrome to debug it? what "Event Listener breakpoints" do I need?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
overflow-y: auto !important;
```

To replace some previous CSS or try create a class in a css file

```
.boxscroll {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

and in your html file:

```
<div class='boxscroll'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem goes on.... - Since the onmouseover event is over the picture element, could it interfere by moving the mouse outside the picture, inside the box that opens? ...if I made myself clear